# Couchdb bad_utf8_character_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, couchdb, couchrest

I am using `couchdb` through `couchrest` in a ruby on rails application. When I try to use `futon` it alerts with a message box saying `bad_utf8_character_code`. If I try to access records from rails console using `Model.all` it raises either of `500:internal server error`,
`RestClient::ServerBrokeConnection: Server broke connection:` or `Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)`
Could any one help me to sort this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue. I tried various curl calls to delete, modify, and even just view the offending document. None of them worked. Finally, I decided to pull the documents down to my local machine one at a time, skip the "bad" one, and then replicate from my local out to production.

- Disable app (so no more records are being written to the db)
- Delete and recreate local database (run these commands in a shell):

  ```
  curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:5984/mydb
  curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/mydb
  ```
- Pull down documents from live to local using this ruby script

> ```
> require 'bundler'
> require 'json'
>
> all_docs = JSON.parse(`curl http://server.com:5984/mydb/_all_docs`)
> docs = all_docs['rows']
> ids = docs.map{|doc| doc['id']}
> bad_ids = ['196ee4a2649b966b13c97672e8863c49']
>
> good_ids = ids - bad_ids
>
> good_ids.each do |curr_id|
>   curr_doc = JSON.parse(`curl http://server.com:5984/mydb/#{curr_id}`)
>   curr_doc.delete('_id')
>   curr_doc.delete('_rev')
>   data = curr_doc.to_json.gsub("\\'", "\'").gsub('"','\"')
>   cmd = %Q~curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/mydb/#{curr_id} -d "#{data}"~
>   puts cmd
>   `#{cmd}`
> end
> ```

- Destroy (delete) and recreate production database (I did this in futon)
- Replicate

  ```
  curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate -d '{"target":"http://server.com:5984/mydb", "source":"http://127.0.0.1:5984/mydb"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  ```
- Restart app